# More files on Android than actual directory after pushing using adb

Tags: android, shell

I pushed a bunch of files on Android sdcard using adb

```
adb push local_path/directory/  device_path/directory/
```

But, once it has pushed all the files, when I counted the number of files on both the computer and the android device, I found more files on Android than actual files on the machine.

```
machinex:My_Tools user$ adb shell ls -R /device_path/directory/ | wc -l    
   36624
machinex:My_Tools user$ ls -R /local_path/directory/ | wc -l
   36617
```

I tried deleting the directory on Android device, and pushing all the files again, but with same result.

Does anyone have any idea, what may be causing the difference. Are there some hidden files on android, that are generated at their own ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `ls -a` command in the so named directory of your board. This will list both hidden and non hidden files in that respective folder.

Steps:

1) adb shell

2) once you are in the board's shell,

cd /path/to/yourdirectory/

3) ls -a

hope this helps you :)